# Unsure how to handle powershell response in .NET

Tags: c#, powershell, asynchronous, imap

I have 2 powershell scripts that I execute from c# which I'm using to first list message using an IMAP cmdlet and the 2nd script performs a view on a specific message. Both execute successfully from powershell, the 2nd one I am trying to retrieve an attachment and I see a bunch of data output to the console like so...

```
   Sent from my iPhone
   ------=_NextPart_000_0027_01CCDAA7.399EBE00
   Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="photo.JPG"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="photo.JPG"

   /9j/4QH6RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAAAAGAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAHAAAAjAESAAMAAAABAAYA
   AAEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAApAITAAMAAAAB
   AAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAuIglAAQAAAABAAABZgAAAABBcHBsZQBpUGhvbmUAAAAAAEgAAAABAAAA
   SAAAAAEyMDA5OjA5OjIwIDE1OjEwOjU1AAAKgp0ABQAAAAEAAAE2kAAABwAAAAQwMjIxkAMAAgAA
   ABQAAAE+kAQAAgAAABQAAAFSkQEABwAAAAQBAgMAoAAABwAAAAQwMTAwoAEAAwAAAAEAAQAAoAIA
   BAAAAAEAAAZAoAMABAAAAAEAAASwpAYAAwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AAAAFMjAwOTowOToyMCAx
```

so it appears everything is fine so far - except there is I believe a difference in the function result as possible a stream/pipe from powershell?

The first one returns a collection of PSObjects which is called like so

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.AddScript(script);
            ps.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
            {
                dynamic val = result.BaseObject;
            }
```

The 2nd script executes without error using Invoke() however trying to retrieve data via for each or

```
dynamic xx = ps2.Invoke();
```

xx is empty;

I thought maybe I need to use BeginInvoke and call asynchronously so I tried

```
    static dynamic GotMail(dynamic o)
    {
        return o;
    }

    delegate dynamic SomeDelegate(dynamic o);

    and attempted to use like so..

          SomeDelegate sd = GotMail;
          IAsyncResult ar = ps2.BeginInvoke();


          dynamic val2 = sd.EndInvoke(ar);
```

and I recieve **"The async result object is null or of an unexpected type."** I'm not even passing parameters into the powershell scripts..everything is hardcoded - the script I run from powershell successfully is exactly what I execute from .NET

Any suggestions for this much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the script twice by calling Invoke() twice.  Remove the first call to invoke e.g.:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddScript(script);
//ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) {
    dynamic val = result.BaseObject;
}
```